# SQLi injection prevention and error reporting issues

Tags: php, mysql, security, code-injection

I know separately these questions are quite common although I have searched around for usable answers and am not having much luck finding a lot of information for MySQLi or the new PHP version. Hopefully one of you experts might be able to help me out.

I have a 'simple' html form running a PHP script to the database, which seems to work perfectly, also includes a file upload, which also works. I have some knowledge over security and protection and I am pretty sure my script isn't at all secure. I am also have problems displaying anything if the script doesn't run properly.

I attempted to add a code such as:

```
} else {
  header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=4');    
}
```

Although there are so many '}' at the end of my code, I am not sure where to add it. Also, there are a lot of issues I may be forgetting to alert the user if the code is unsuccessful and the error would never be displayed?

Here is my code so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['pcn'])){
    $pcn_number = $_POST['pcn_number'];
    $vehicle_reg = $_POST['vehicle_reg'];
    $street_name = $_POST['street_name'];
    $offence = $_POST['offence'];
    $vehicle_make = $_POST['vehicle_make'];
    $vehicle_model = $_POST['vehicle_model'];
    $vehicle_colour = $_POST['vehicle_colour'];
    $date_issued = $_POST['date_issued'];
    $time_issued = $_POST['time_issued'];
    $witnessed_from = $_POST['witnessed_from'];
    $witnessed_to = $_POST['witnessed_to'];
    $issued_by = $_POST['issued_by'];



$target_dir = "evidence/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["evidence"]["name"]);
$name = $_FILES["evidence"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["evidence"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo '';
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["evidence"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
}   

if(empty($pcn_number) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
if(empty($vehicle_reg) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
if(empty($street_name) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
    if(empty($offence) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
    if(empty($vehicle_make) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
    if(empty($vehicle_colour) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
if(empty($date_issued) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
if(empty($time_issued) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
if(empty($witnessed_from) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
if(empty($witnessed_to) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
if(empty($issued_by) === true){
    header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=2');  
} else {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO parkingtickets (id, pcn_number, date_issued, vehicle_reg, vehicle_make, vehicle_model, vehicle_colour, street_name, witnessed_from, witnessed_to, time_issued, offence, issued_by, special_fine_discount, special_fine, paid, paid_date, evidence) VALUES ('','$pcn_number', '$date_issued', '$vehicle_reg', '$vehicle_make', '$vehicle_model', '$vehicle_colour', '$street_name', '$witnessed_from', '$witnessed_to', '$time_issued', '$offence', '$issued_by', '', '', '0', '', '$name')"); 
header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=3');  
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
} 
}
```

I know that you guys will see it as the wrong way to go about it, but I'm still a novice, and hopefully you'll be able to point me in the right direction with a few better examples as error reporting for this code as well as MySQLi injection prevention could be improved drastically.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, just so you know - the users for this code will be staff members with password protected accounts and such so hacking shouldn't be a drastic issue, would just like it protected slightly more than it is, just in case.

Comment: 1. [How to prevent SQL injection](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) 2. Learn to use whitespace, it makes your life a lot easier. 3. Always `exit;` after you set a Location header, otherwise the script will continue to execute. 4. File uploading is actually kind of complicated (working on a blog post about it right now).

Comment: In attempting to add white space, I discovered that you're nesting else/ifs. Just so you're aware, PHP has `elseif`.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/MYZss

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ScottArciszewski, I will have a look through, it seems to be a lot simpler. Will you be posting the blog link once finished? It would become pretty handy for the type of website I am working on!

Comment: Yeah, I just hit a bit of writer's block this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes at your code. For consistency i used underscore for all variables and not the camelCase convention. Same for table name in database (parking_tickets).
It is a good practice to validate your inputs so if one of them isn't of correct type you will be able to show info messages for it.
Also, i used associative arrays instead of multiple if statements.
Thanks to @ Scott Arciszewski i added the prepared statements with the difference i omit the paid column so make sure it has 0 as default value in your database.

```
if (isset($_POST['pcn'])) {

    $pcn_number = $_POST['pcn_number'];
    $vehicle_reg = $_POST['vehicle_reg'];
    $street_name = $_POST['street_name'];
    $offence = $_POST['offence'];
    $vehicle_make = $_POST['vehicle_make'];
    $vehicle_model = $_POST['vehicle_model'];
    $vehicle_colour = $_POST['vehicle_colour'];
    $date_issued = $_POST['date_issued'];
    $time_issued = $_POST['time_issued'];
    $witnessed_from = $_POST['witnessed_from'];
    $witnessed_to = $_POST['witnessed_to'];
    $issued_by = $_POST['issued_by'];

    //User input validation chekcs

    $is_valid = true;

    //e.g
    if (!(is_numeric((int)$pcn_number) && ctype_digit((string)$pcn_number))) {
        $is_valid = false;
        echo 'The pcn_number is not valid. It must be an integer.';
    }

    if (!(is_numeric((int)$vehicle_reg) && ctype_digit((string)$vehicle_reg))) {
        $is_valid = false;
        echo 'The vehicle_reg is not valid. It must be an integer.';
    }

    if (!$is_valid) {
        //Do something here and dont continue if one of the inputs is not valid
    }

    $target_dir = "evidence/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["evidence"]["name"]);
    $name = $_FILES["evidence"]["name"];
    $upload_ok = true;
    $image_file_type = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["evidence"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        $upload_ok = true;
    } else {
        $upload_ok = false;
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $upload_ok = false;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    $valid_formats = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    if (!in_array($image_file_type, $valid_formats)) {
        $upload_ok = false;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to false by an error
    if ($upload_ok === false) {
        echo '';
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["evidence"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo '';
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
    }

    $checks = array(
        array (
            'var'=>$pcn_number,
            'condition'=>true,
            'location'=>'addpcn.php?pcnerror=2'
        ),
        array (
            'var'=>$vehicle_reg,
            'condition'=>true,
            'location'=>'addpcn.php?pcnerror=2'
        ),
        /*
         * More elements here
        */
    );

    foreach($checks as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value['var']) === $value['condition'] ) {
            header('Location: '.$value['location']);
            exit;
        }
    }

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'your_password', 'your_database');
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO parking_tickets (pcn_number, date_issued, vehicle_reg, vehicle_make, vehicle_model, vehicle_colour, street_name, witnessed_from, witnessed_to, time_issued, offence, issued_by, evidence) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
    if (mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssss', $pcn_number, $date_issued, $vehicle_reg, $vehicle_make, $vehicle_model, $vehicle_colour, $street_name, $witnessed_from, $witnessed_to, $time_issued, $offence, $issued_by, $name)) {
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         header('Location: addpcn.php?pcnerror=3');  
         exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: `is_numeric((int)$var)` is obsolete.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution @Gumbo. I suppose the following is better:if ( !(filter_var($pcn_number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === 0 || !filter_var($pcn_number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) ) {
 $is_valid = false;
 echo 'The pcn_number is not valid. It must be an integer.';
}

Comment: Thank you so much for the script edit, does adding this require any changes to the database? As like you said about underscoring the "parkingtickets" to "parking_tickets". I will upload the script tonight and take a good lesson from it, need to start learning more about the right way to code.

Comment: You have to change only the table name and set default 0 as the default value for 'paid' column: RENAME parkingtickets TO parking_tickets; ALTER TABLE parking_tickets ALTER COLUMN paid SET DEFAULT '0';

Comment: Also, it's better to check all the user inputs first and upload the file only if those are valid. Otherwise you will have inconsistency among your database and your uploaded files.